# Recreate Module with Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

I implemented my modules to be singleton in my UI application. I used Require.js to load them.
I need a way to destroy some module and recreate it again by Require.
Is there a way to do it?

Here is an example of one of the modules:

```
define(['viewmodels/factory'], function (factory) {
    var vm = factory.createViewModel(function () {  
        var baseViewModel = this; 
        var self = this;
    });
    return new vm();    // create as singleton
});

define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        createViewModel: function (ctor) {
            ctor.prototype = new (require("viewmodels/baseViewModel"))();
            ctor.prototype.constructor = ctor;
            return ctor;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't think singleton is the way forward if you actually need to re-instantiate them. Can you give us more details on how your "singleton" modules are implemented? and what you mean by "destroy some module"?

Comment: Please see my updated question with the module code

Comment: I used the unfef method and it did the trick .